# Repeat audio file on iPod without pause

Tags: itunes, audio, ipod, ipod-nano

I want to loop a 10 second audio file (originally a CAF file, converted to Mp3 and Mp4) on two different iPods (both nanos), but on both devices and in both formats there is a short gap between repeats. When I repeat the file in iTunes there is no gap at all.

Is this a shortcoming of the iPods, or is there some setting I can change?

Comment: iTunes has a feature called “gapless playback” if I remember correctly. Check if there’s something like that in the Nano’s settings.

Comment: @herrbischoff Yes I read about that too, but didn't see anything like it on the Nano's settings.